# Dynamic ion-grid with 2 columns

Tags: ionic-framework

i'm trying to create ion-grid with me just to columns dynamically,

just like this but dynamically

```
  <ion-grid fixed >
      <ion-row>
       <ion-col > 1</ion-col>
       <ion-col > 2</ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row>
       <ion-col > 3</ion-col>
       <ion-col > 4</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-grid-g7bwcr?file=pages/home/home.html)

```
   <ion-grid fixed >
      <ion-row *ngFor="let cus of customer; let i = index">
       <ion-col>{{ cus.name }}</ion-col>
       <ion-col >  <img [src]="cus.image"  class="imgCardMain" /></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
```

.ts file

```
imgaddress="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAHQAxwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAACAgMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQMGAAECBwj/xAA6EAACAQMDAgQDBwMDBAMB";


    customer = [{
        "name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "city" : "Berlin",
        "image" : this.imgaddress,
        "price":10
    },{
        "name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "city" : "Berlin",
        "image" :this.imgaddress,
         "price":10
    },{
        "name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "city" : "Berlin",
        "image" : this.imgaddress,
         "price":10
    },{
        "name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "city" : "Berlin",
        "image" : this.imgaddress,
         "price":10
    }]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i want to display just 2 columns,the rest of data goes to the next row

Comment: Hey! I use your answer. just for explaining. I hope u don't mind. If u want to remove my ans then I'll do that. @ORBIT

Comment: why are you doing like that.how about my effort and why dont you give vote ,and removing question @HassanAli

Comment: I used your answer and add one thing therefore I'm taking permission to you to use your answer just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-grid fixed >
  <ion-row *ngFor="let cus of customer">
   <ion-col size="6">{{ cus.name }}</ion-col>
   <ion-col size="6">  <img [src]="cus.image"  class="imgCardMain" /></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

You just need to add size. colum size depends on you but remembers one row has 12 col so as you need u can manage it by your self.